# Is there a way to improve the quality of icon images in Google Maps KmlLayer?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, kml

I am trying to implement `google.maps.KmlLayer` to render hundreds of markers server-sided as opposed to creating `google.maps.Marker` for each datapoint, which can slow down the browser. However, the rendered tile from Google's server seems to be a bit of low quality, you can take a look for comparison  [here on my testpage](http://www.bussup.com/testkmllayer.html)

(The ones with shadow are created with Marker class, while the ones without are from KML Layer. Both set are generated from the same .png images)

It seems to be an issue with bitdepth or something, as the `<scale>` tag in KML is already set to be 1 . So, is there a way to improve the quality of image from KmlLayer, or should I resort to something else if I decided the low-quality icon image is not acceptable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The loaded tiles from Google KmlLayer server seem to be normal 8 bit png images, but possibly with lossy compression since their size are relatively small. Therefor the question might be changed to how can I turn off the compression, if possible? (Actually, what bothers me is not the loss of color, but the aliasing.).